# How to stop the Timer after specific amount of time?

Tags: angular, countdowntimer

In my below code  have start the Timer in ngOnInit() and I want to stop the timer when user complete the test by clicking the completeTest() method,

in below code  I have set the notification for 1-1 minute to test the whether timer is stop or not.

but after I have complete the test still the timer is running in background and the toastr notification still display on next page also.
plz give solution for how to stop the timer.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit, QueryList, Renderer2, ViewChild, 
ViewChildren,} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginService } from 'src/Services/login.service';
import { TryReportService } from 'src/Services/try-report.service';
@Component({
selector: 'app-start-exam',
templateUrl: './start-exam.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./start-exam.component.css'],
})
export class StartExamComponent implements OnInit {

selectedOptionIndex: number = -1;
questions:any[] = [];
selectedOptions: number[] = [];
questionTexts: any;
UserResultData:any[]=[];
selectedOptionsMap: { [questionId: string]: number } = {};
currentTime: Date = new Date();
// Add a variable to store the total time in seconds (30 minutes)
totalTimeInSeconds: number = 30 * 60;
private timerInterval: any;
showLoader:boolean = true;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private _router: Router, private _tryReportService: 
TryReportService, private _loginService:LoginService, private _route: ActivatedRoute, private 
_toastr: ToastrService) { }

 testObj: any;
 subjectName:any;
 chapter_id:any;
 answeredQuestions: { questionId: string; answer: string; selectedOptionId?: any }[] = [];

 ngOnInit() {
 this.findCurrentQuestion();
 this.findAnsweredQuestions();
 this.findNotAttemptedQuestions();
 this.findAnsweredQuestionValues();
 this.findVisitedNotAnsweredQuestions();
 this.subjectName = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('s_name');
 this.chapter_id = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('chapter_id');
 this._loginService.getQuestions(this.subjectName, this.chapter_id).subscribe((apiResponse: 
 any) => {
 this.showLoader = false;
 if (apiResponse.status && apiResponse.all_question && 
  Array.isArray(apiResponse.all_question)) {
  this.questions = apiResponse.all_question.map((apiQuestion:any) => {
    return {
      id: apiQuestion.id,
      question: apiQuestion.question,
      options: [
        apiQuestion.optiona,
        apiQuestion.optionb,
        apiQuestion.optionc,
        apiQuestion.optiond,
      ],
      // correctAnswer: // Your logic to map the correct answer based on the API response,
     };
     });
     } else {
     console.error('API response is not as expected:', apiResponse);
   }
   }, (error) => {
   }, () => {
   });
   for (const answeredQuestion of this.answeredQuestions) {
    this.selectedOptionsMap[answeredQuestion.questionId] = answeredQuestion.selectedOptionId;
   } 
     const remainingTimeInSeconds = this.calculateRemainingTime();
   if (remainingTimeInSeconds !== undefined) {
   this.totalTimeInSeconds = remainingTimeInSeconds;
    }

    setInterval(() => {
   this.updateTimer();
   }, 1000);
    }
   ngOnDestroy() {
   if (this.timerInterval) {
  clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
   }
   }
   calculateRemainingTime(): number | undefined {
   // Calculate the remaining time by subtracting the current time from the end time
   const endTime = new Date();
   endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes() + 30);
    const remainingTimeInSeconds = Math.floor((endTime.getTime() - this.currentTime.getTime()) 
    / 1000);
    return remainingTimeInSeconds >= 0 ? remainingTimeInSeconds : undefined;
    }

    updateTimer() {
    if (this.totalTimeInSeconds > 0) {
    this.totalTimeInSeconds -= 1;
    if(this.totalTimeInSeconds === 29 * 60){
     this._toastr.warning('WARNING! , Only 10 min left!')
    }
    if(this.totalTimeInSeconds === 28 * 60){
    this._toastr.error('hurry up , Only 5 min left!, EXAM WILL AUTO-SUBMIT AFTER TIME END');
     }
    } else {
     // Timer reached zero, handle the event (e.g., display a message, complete the test)
     clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
     this.completeTest();
    }
    }
   formatTime(seconds: number): string {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
     return `${this.pad(minutes)}:${this.pad(remainingSeconds)}`;
     }

    pad(val: number): string {
    val < 10 ? `0${val}` : `${val}`;
    }

    isQuestionAnswered(questionIndex: number): boolean {
    return this.answeredQuestions.some(answer => answer.questionId === 
    this.questions[questionIndex].id);
    }
    currentQuestion = 0;

  notAttemptedQuestions:any;
   answeredQuestionValues:any;
   visitedNotAnsweredQuestions:any;

  findCurrentQuestion() {
   const currentQuestion = this.currentQuestion;
   const question = this.questions[currentQuestion];
   }

   // Find Answered Questions
   findAnsweredQuestions() {
   const answeredQuestions = this.answeredQuestions.map(answer => {
   const question = this.questions.find((q:any) => q.id === answer.questionId);
    return { ...answer, question };
    });
    // console.log('Answered Questions:', answeredQuestions);
    }

     findAnsweredQuestionValues() {
      this.answeredQuestionValues = this.answeredQuestions.map(answer => {
       return {
      questionId: answer.questionId,
         selectedAnswer: answer.answer,
    selectedOptionId: answer.selectedOptionId 
     };
    });
       // console.log('Answered Questions Values:', this.answeredQuestionValues);
       }

          // Find Not Attempted Questions
          findNotAttemptedQuestions() {
           this.notAttemptedQuestions = this.questions.filter((question:any) => {
         return !this.answeredQuestions.some(answer => answer.questionId === question.id);
           });
         // console.log('not attempted questions --',this.notAttemptedQuestions);
              }

                 findVisitedNotAnsweredQuestions() {
                this.visitedNotAnsweredQuestions = this.questions.filter((question: any) => {
             // Check if the question is visited but not answered
              const questionId = question.id;
                const isVisited = this.testObj?.data?.questions[questionId]?.visited ?? false;
               const isAnswered = this.answeredQuestions.some((answered: any) => 
           answered.questionId === questionId);
           return isVisited && !isAnswered;
               });
               // console.log('Visited but not Answered Questions:', 
              this.visitedNotAnsweredQuestions);
           }

          selectMCQ(event: any, optionIndex: any) {
          const selectedAnswer = this.questions[this.currentQuestion].options[optionIndex];
          const questionId = this.questions[this.currentQuestion].id;
          this.selectedOptionsMap[questionId] = optionIndex;
             const existingAnswerIndex = this.answeredQuestions.findIndex(
            (q) => q.questionId === questionId
              );
          if (existingAnswerIndex !== -1) {
            this.answeredQuestions[existingAnswerIndex].answer = selectedAnswer;
              this.answeredQuestions[existingAnswerIndex].selectedOptionId = optionIndex; // 
            Store the selected option ID
          } else {
            this.answeredQuestions.push({ questionId, answer: selectedAnswer, 
          selectedOptionId: optionIndex });
          }
              // console.log('question and answer', this.answeredQuestions);
                }

           nextQuestion() {
         if (this.currentQuestion < this.questions.length - 1) {
          this.currentQuestion++;
           }
            const currentQuestionId = this.questions[this.currentQuestion].id;
           const attemptedAnswer = this.answeredQuestions.find(
            (q) => q.questionId === currentQuestionId
             );
             if (attemptedAnswer) {
          // console.log(`Question ID: ${currentQuestionId}, Attempted 
           Answer:${attemptedAnswer.answer}`);
          } else {
             }
             this.findCurrentQuestion();
           this.findAnsweredQuestions();
            this.findNotAttemptedQuestions();
           this.findAnsweredQuestionValues();
                this.findVisitedNotAnsweredQuestions();
                }

           previousQuestion() {
              if (this.currentQuestion > 0) {
              this.currentQuestion--;
                 }
                 }

                jumpToQuestion(questionIndex: any) {
                  this.currentQuestion = questionIndex;
              }

               completeTest() {
              clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
              const score: any= 5;
               document.getElementById("dimissModal")?.click();
             const selected_by_user: any[] = [];
                // Create a separate array with information about all questions
              const allQuestionsInfo = this.questions.map((question) => {
                  const answer = this.answeredQuestions.find((a) => a.questionId === 
          question.id);
           const selectedOption = answer ? this.getOptionLetter(answer.selectedOptionId) : '';
             selected_by_user.push({
              id: question.id,
              selected_answer: selectedOption,
           });
            return {
              id: question.id,
               selected_answer: selectedOption,
            };
               });
            this._loginService.getResult({selected_by_user}).subscribe((response:any) =>{
          console.log('getting result',response.data);
             this.UserResultData = response.data;
             this._loginService.resultData = this.UserResultData;
              this._tryReportService.correctAnswer = response.data.correctAnswer;
                 this._tryReportService.totalMarks = response.data.totalMarks;
                this._tryReportService.totalQuestions = response.data.totalQuestions;
           this._tryReportService.unattempts = response.data.unattempts;
            this._tryReportService.wrongAnswer = response.data.wrongAnswer;
             this._router.navigate([`/report`]);
                });
           }
                 getOptionLetter(index: number | undefined): string {
               const optionLetters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
                 return index !== undefined ? optionLetters[index] : '';
             }
             }
```

Comment: please share a minimal reproducible example in a stackblitz where the issue happens and what needs to be fixed!

Comment: @NarenMurali actually i have start the timer in ngOnInit(){
    setInterval(() => {
    this.updateTimer();
  }, 1000);
}

and after few minutes want to stope these timer how to do these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code to clear the interval. You can do the  clear either with a button, or a `setTimeout` that runs after 5 seconds

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <button (click)="clear()">clear</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  setIntervalRef: number | null = null;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.setIntervalRef = setInterval(() => {
      this.updateTimer();
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.clear();
    }, 5000)
  }

  updateTimer() {
    console.log('test');
  }

  clear() {
    if (this.setIntervalRef) {
      clearInterval(this.setIntervalRef);
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-paw2nn?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)